# Javascript perform click on html "image" in old browser

Tags: javascript, image, browser, onclick

I'm trying to perform a click on a `<image>` element. I discovered that:

> [3] Older versions had HTMLInputElement.click(), and HTMLButtonElement.click() only.

Does someone know how can i trigger the same event by other way ?

Thank you

**EDIT: .click() works on all browsers. But i need to do this on Android's 2.3 browser, and it gives me:**

```
01-10 21:19:18.375 4786-4786/com.example.victormilazzo.siganotifier E/Web Console: TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById('btnLogin2').click' [undefined] is not a function. at undefined:1
```

**SOLVED USING CODE BELOW**

As i said, old browser only supports click() method on input or button elements. So, i tried:

```
function simulateclick(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('btnLogin2');
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, elem);
    elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
var btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
btn.addEventListener('click', simulateclick);
btn.click();
```

PS.: 'btnLogin2' was the id of the element i was trying to click. It's a `<div>`.

**Explanation:** I just created a button and added an eventlistener that simulates a click event

Thank you all !

Comment: which browser and version are you planning to work on?

Comment: you can click on anything in IE6 and above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the click event only on input or button elements if you´r targeting older browsers.
The problem can be solved by styling an button with the css property **background-image**.

- Add an image to the button
- set the **background-color** to **white**
- set the **border** to **none**

In the code example you see how this work:

```js
var clickCounter = 0;
var messageBox = document.getElementById("message");

function clickMe() {
  clickCounter++;
  messageBox.innerHTML = "Clicked " + clickCounter + " times";
}
```

```css
button {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7);
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickMe()"></button>
<p id="message">Click me</p>
```

**EDIT:**

Android browser does not support the click event as you can see in the MDN documentations.[click documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: No problem mate. Maybe you can accept this anwser as the right one?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really test this, but if you use the `onClick` property and point to a JS function that does the click event, that should do the trick.

JS:

```
function imageClick() { // do clicky stuff }
```

And markup

```
<img src="img.jpg" onclick="imageClick()" />
```